# Retrieve only messages that publisher send after subscriber connected(masstransit)

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, masstransit

I have created an application that works using MassTransit and Azure Service Bus as transport. Publish, send, retrieve events and commands - this is all works good. But now I want to create subscriber that will retrieve messages that publisher send after subscriber connected. How to do that? I do not want to get all messages that was sended by publisher before connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible.

By definition, a publisher only sends to subscribers. If a subscriber is not connected at the time an event is published, that subscriber would not receive it. Only the subscribers that are connected at the time the event is published receive the event.

In the future, MassTransit will add support for Kafka and Event Hub, which will support what you want, but the semantics for those transports are quite different.

Comment: Depending upon the weather, early support for Event Hub might be ready by next week...

Comment: I have tested this right now. Steps:
1. Close subscriber
2. Send message from publisher
3. Open subscriber
Result: I've a message in subscriber.
This works as you say if I create new subscriber(with new queue).

Comment: @АлександрГребенюк that's correct. Once the subscriber has connected once, the messages will build up on the queue when disconnected and be available upon reconnection.

Comment: Kafka and EventHub support sounds exciting, Chris :)